# Append an existing <DIV> with a child DIV using a new ID for each item in an array

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild, createelement

I'm trying to loop through an array and add a div for each item of the array with a numbered ID correlating to the item's index of the array.  This ID would be later used to add further content to the newly generated child divs.

My code:

HTML

```
<div id="resultsBox" class="results"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var resultsArr = [apple, orange, banana]

for (var i = 0; i < resultsArr.length; i++) {
  var resultDiv = document.createElement("div")
  resultDiv.setAttribute(id, "result" + i)
  resultsBox.appendChild(resultDiv) 
}
```

I would expect that this would change the HTML to:

```
<div id="resultsBox" class="results">
  <div id="result0"></div>
  <div id="result1"></div>
  <div id="result2"></div>
<div>
```

but for me it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var resultsArr = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
var resultsBox = document.getElementById('resultsBox');

for (var i = 0; i < resultsArr.length; i++) {
  var resultDiv = document.createElement("div");
  resultDiv.id = "result" + i;
  resultDiv.innerHTML = resultsArr[i]; // just to see the div.
  resultsBox.appendChild(resultDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="resultsBox" class="results"></div>
```

The problem that you had was using the `setAttribute` function. It won't work well with `id`. This is mainly because the `id` is a property and not an attribute.